# Click event doesn't work for overlapping foreignObject in svg

Tags: javascript, svg, event-handling, foreignobject

I have an svg element like this,

```
<svg class="makeStyles-timeline-17" width="100%" height="1920" overflow="auto">
   <foreignObject position="absolute" width="100%" height="1920" pointer-events="all">
      <div>
         <div id="timelineRow_0" data-index="0" data-time="Wed Dec 09 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0600 (Bangladesh Standard Time)" style="height: 20px;"></div>
      </div>
   </foreignObject>
   <foreignObject position="absolute" width="100%" height="1920" pointer-events="all">
      <div style="height: 20px"> Test</div>
   </foreignObject>
 </svg>
```

There are click events for the child element inside both foreignObject. The foreignObjects are overlapping each other. My problem is the click event for the last foreignObject's child is working fine when I click on that div. But click event is not firing for the first foreignObject's child even though the last foreignObject's div is not overlapping the first foreignObject's div. In short the click events doesn't go through the top foreignObject. It blocks the click event there.

Comment: Works fine for me. Perhaps it's a bug in the browser you're using, if so report it to the relevant browser's bugtracker.

Comment: When the html element inside the foreignObjects are overlapping I want the top element's event to be fired.

Comment: It is fired. Note that the two foreignObject elements in your testcase completely overlap so you won't get anything from the lower element.

Comment: `Note that the two foreignObject elements in your testcase completely overlap so you won't get anything from the lower element.` Is it impossible to make it work? Should I create the svg in a different way to solve my problem?

Comment: Depends what you want to do. Put everything in the one foreignObject might work.